# Removing hover box on WordPress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a **WordPress** theme called **Enigma** and I'm having trouble removing the hover effect. The effect creates a whitebox over the link. I've tried a lot of ways to remove it but it still remains.

Here is the link to the website.

http://www.capcar.com.au/wp

The effect I mention is on the **NavBar**.

Answer (score 0):

Search for class

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
```

remove background color and box shadow property

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
```

This class overriding background color property set this value too.

Hope it will help you

Comment: this didnt help im sorry